# How to track my software available as link on other websites

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, api, anti-piracy

I need to track my software available as link on other websites.
I want information of those websites who make my software as downloadable link available on their website without my permission.

Please help me out in finding out some good related articles or solutions

Answer (score 5):

Enable the web server logs, and track the Referer HTTP header for all requests to your software package.

Of course, that would only help track sites that directly link to your site. There is no easy way to track websites that mirror your package and allow users to download it from the mirror.

Comment: Yeah totally with Franci on this, @Shann you're in an arms-race where even referer may only be populated for A/@HREF tags.  Even that could be evaded with a script or mirroring.